# Mapbox iOS SDK 3.1 How to make Annotation Callout sticky

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

i just started developing in iOS. So sorry if the problem seems to be trivial:

I load several markers / annotations via SwiftyJSON from an API and display those on a Mapbox MapView. When clicking on the annotation the callout is triggered. - this works fine and easy as hell.
The Problem: I'd like to center the mapView on the marker / annotation and callout, or move the camera to show them in the center, zoomed in. Whenever I use something like this:

```
    let camera = MGLMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: annotation.coordinate, fromDistance: 1000, pitch: 0, heading: 0)
    mapView.setCamera(camera, withDuration: 2, animationTimingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut))
```

or

```
    mapView.setCenterCoordinate(annotation.coordinate, zoomLevel: 15, animated: true)
```

The callout just stays in the same position. What I would like to achieve is, that it's displayed sticky on top of the annotation / marker.

This is my complete code for this part (building of the annotations in viewdidload not included:

```
func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, imageForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
    var annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImageWithIdentifier("marker_live")

    if annotationImage == nil {
        // Leaning Tower of Pisa by Stefan Spieler from the Noun Project
        var image = UIImage(named: "marker_live")!
        image = image.imageWithAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, image.size.height/2, 0))

        annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage(image: image, reuseIdentifier: "marker_live")
    }

    return annotationImage
}


func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
    print("tap on annotation")
    mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)

    return true
}

func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, calloutViewForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> UIView? {

    return CustomCalloutView(representedObject: annotation)

}

func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, tapOnCalloutForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
    print("Tapped the callout for: \(annotation.title!)")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("PlaylistFromMap", sender: annotation.title!)
    mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
}
```

I also thought about using a completion handler, but didn't understood how it works.
Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The position of a callout view currently cannot be updated after it has been displayed, but [this is a feature](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3154) we’re looking to add in v3.3.0.

To open the callout after a `setCamera:` or `setCoordinate:` animation, use the variants of those methods that includes a completion handler and then `selectAnnotation:` there.

Comment: So far understood... but how can I then detect the touch on the annotation? So far there are two delegates -mapView:didSelectAnnotation:
and -mapView:annotationCanShowCallout: i used to detect the touch. With the first one i can trigger the camera movement and after the select the annotation (again) after the completionHandler. With the second I could show the callout. How can i trigger the camera and selection without actually selecting the annotation in the first place?

Comment: You can’t — at least, not with any method the Mapbox iOS SDK provides.

Comment: My problem is, that I use the the `selectAnnotation` to trigger the camera... so either I need a way to trigger the camera separately or the callout. Any tipps what I could look for?